# I want to add a progressbar

Tags: wpf, multithreading, progress-bar

```
<Window x:Class="ASTHENIA.Loading"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Loading" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="load"  Height="12" Margin="54,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205"/>

</Grid>
```

I set up the progressbar，load.Maximum=100,and the min is 0. How to let the progressbar loading over after 5mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="12" Margin="54,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205">
   <ProgressBar.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
         <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
               <DoubleAnimation
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                  From="0" To="100" Duration="0:5:0" 
               />
            </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
   </ProgressBar.Triggers>
</ProgressBar>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But can you teach me how to close the window when my progressbar.valve==100

Comment: @Bubble: Try the [`Storyboard`s `Completed` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx).